# bumblebee optirun not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

i installed bumblebee to switch between GPU but when i run the commande optirun i get the following message
[   97.796880] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

[   97.796906] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
i have installed the nvidia drivers, but the GPU declare itself as 3d controller not VGA compatible
06:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)

Answer (score 2):

I had the exactly same problem today. Here's a quick way I solved it:

1. Open `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`
2. Find the line that begins with `XorgModulePath` and change it to:

```
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input
```

3. Save the file and restart bumblebeed:

```
sudo systemctl restart bumblebeed
```

This solution should work for similar errors where a `mouse` module is missing.

Comment: i did it and now i receive this error

Comment: [GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
[GFX1-]: glxtest: process failed (received signal 11)

Comment: @aminekhazraj You should try the GPU without bumblebee first. Try `sudo prime-select nvidia`, then reboot and open the NVIDIA X Server settings. To switch back, use these commands: `sudo prime-select intel && sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf && sudo update-initramfs -u`. Again, reboot after switching the GPU. To use bumblebee, the Intel GPU must be selected with the blacklist-nvidia file removed.

Comment: @aminekhazraj I just got this error too. Which program did you launch with optirun? For me, it only happens with programs like Firefox. Try `optirun glxgears` (install `glxgears` first). If you see the gears spinning, you should be fine.

Comment: I did the first steps and now the laptop won’t turn on

Comment: @aminekhazraj It seems the NVIDIA driver fails to start. Edit your question with the output of `dmesg` when the NVIDIA GPU is selected (look for lines starting with NVRM). The laptop should turn on if you select the integrated GPU again, try `sudo prime-select intel` in recovery mode.

Comment: This worked for on `Linux [hostname] 5.15.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 27 15:51:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`